# An efficient way to concatenate rows of a 2-dim array according to a given list of pairs of indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 2 dimensional array with a very large number of rows, and a list of pairs of indexes of that array. I want to create a new 2 dim array, whose rows are concatenations of the rows of the original array, made according to the list of pairs of indexes. For example:

```
a =
 
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

0 0 0


indexes = [[0,0], [0,1], [2,3]]
```

the returned array should be:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3

1 2 3 4 5 6

7 8 9 0 0 0
```

Obviously I can iterate the list of indexes, but my question is whether there is a more efficient way of doing this. I should say that the list of indexes is also very large.

Answer (score 0):

First convert *indexes* to a *Numpy* array:

```
ind = np.array(indexes)
```

Then generate your result as:

```
result = np.concatenate([a[ind[:,0]], a[ind[:,1]]], axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Another possible formula (with the same result):

```
result = np.concatenate([ a[ind[:,i]] for i in range(ind.shape[1]) ], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using `NumPy` as:

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
print(a)

b = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 3]]
b = np.array(b)
print(b)

c = a[b.reshape(-1)].reshape(-1, a.shape[1]*b.shape[1])
print(c)

'''
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]

[[0 0]
 [1 1]
 [2 3]]

[[ 0  1  2  0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal stacking `np.hstack`:

```
c = np.array(indexes)
np.hstack((a[c[:,0]],a[c[:,1]]))
```

output:

```
[[1 2 3 1 2 3]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [7 8 9 0 0 0]]
```